# Stream audio from one device to another

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, audio-streaming

I am looking to create a project where user A will stream audio and user B will receive it, I am not looking to upload the audio into a WebServer and then Download it. I have done quite a lot of research but I didn't come to a final design. I am asking for guides and not for you to design my application, where am I supposed to start with such a project?

I have a design in mind but not sure how feasible is it with IOS xamarin.
I would like to know your thoughts on this design.

1. User A will choose audio file from their playlist
2. Then I want to decode that audio into bits (Packets) and then send packets over to User B
3. User B will receive these packets and then encode them back to be an audio file

I am looking to achieve this using HTTP protocol. This is what I was able to get to. I am welcoming any ideas or guides as to where I should start with such a project.

P.S. I don't mind switching to swift/objective-C if it's not possible with Xamarin.

Comment: isn't it same as internet calling... have you checked..how internal calling works?

Comment: Not sure if internet calling will work for my project but I will take a look at it.

Comment: you can copy the transferring of voice concept and how it encrypt and decrypt... then just switch it with audio file :)

Comment: Absolutely correct, not sure how come that never came to my mind :) anyways post your answer and if I dont get any other answer soon I will accept yours. In the mean time I will do some research on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the voice transferring concept from the Internet calling concept. You will get the idea regarding how the voice is being transferred along with encryption and decryption of the packets.

You can get a little brief from [here](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/ip-telephony.htm) and [here](http://searchunifiedcommunications.techtarget.com/feature/How-does-VoIP-work-A-technical-guide-to-functional-VoIP).

Once you can get the hang of it, you can easily switch with the audio files which you wants to play.